# use curl to download and yum to install (NTLM proxy issues)

Tags: linux, proxy, fedora, yum, curl

I need to use a wi-fi under a corporate environment with my Fedora 21. It uses NTLM. With curl i've been able to reach sites (yahoo) setting the proxy, the type of proxy, the user and the password, but with yum I couldn't (I mean, I setted the proxy/user/password, but there is no setting I'd found to say that I want to use NTLM auth)

Theoretically I could use cntlm package to do so, but I cannot use yum to install it...

Is there a way to download the package using curl and then install it using yum?

ANY workaround is welcome. E.g.: if I can use a windows machine to download the package, copy it with a usb stick and then install it using yum, i'll be equally happy. But for the cases where I cannot count on having a windows and a linux, the best answer would be one involving just linux :)

In case it helps: `yum list cntlm` says:

```
cntlm.x86_64 0.92.3-7.fc21 fedora
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on fedora 20, so I ran yumdownloader for you asking for fedora 21 and
the list of dependencies:

```
$ yumdownloader --urls  --resolve --releasever=21 cntlm
http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/fedora/linux/releases/21/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/cntlm-0.92.3-7.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

As you can see there are no dependencies. So you can download this rpm
with curl (it is arbitrarily from a mirror in France) and install it with
rpm -i (or yum install).

```
$ curl http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/fedora/linux/releases/21/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/cntlm-0.92.3-7.fc21.x86_64.rpm >/tmp/cntlm.rpm
$ sudo rpm -i /tmp/cntlm.rpm
$ # or sudo yum install /tmp/cntlm.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

For cntlm   use yumdownloader --download-only  then use rpm -iVh  to install it

then use cntlm as would desire.

Comment: thanks, but couldn't figure out how to configure the ntlm proxy with yumdownloader